# How to dynamically create variable names? Or should I simply use a dictionary?

Tags: python, game-theory

I'm writing a program in python to transform games from characteristic form into normal form. I've already read some answers to similar questions: most people say it's preferable to use a dictionary. But I think the problem remains if you want to give specific names to the keys.

Let's say I want to build a program for games with three players, that's easy:

```
v1 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(1)?"))
v2 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(2)?"))
v3 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(3)?"))
v12 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(1,2)?"))
v13 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(1,3)?"))
v23 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(2,3)?"))
v123 = int(raw_input("How much is worth the coalition v(1,2,3)?"))
# and then I continue with the program
```

But if I want to build a program for games with n players ...
Sure, I can build a a dictionary, but still, I don't know how to call every key the way I want it (v1, v2, v3,...  ..., v123..n). Any ideas?

Comment: **What?** I wish I could leave it at that but I have 10 more characters to go.

Comment: Yes; you want a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, you should use a dictionary, or possibly a class, but probably a dictionary.

Comment: sorry, I pressed enter before finishing. Now I've finished

Comment: It is unclear, which variable is assigned to which player. Normally one would have one object per player which encapsulates all related data. You should at least rename the variables above so one can see which one belongs to which player. Yes, that might be a bit typing, but it's you who wants proper help, right? And you should get the question right and clear.

Answer (score 0):

The easies way is to have a container class, createn an empty instance and add attributes to it as required:

```
class MyContainer(object):
    pass

my_container = MyContainer()
my_container.first_var = 1
my_container.next_var = "Hello"
...
```

But there are certainly much better ways, depending on your application.
For Python3, you can/should omit the object base-class.

In case you want to create variable names dynamically (whyever that should be necessary here), you could use:

```
setattr(my_container, "a_string_with_the_name_of_the_attribute", "the value")
```

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter unintentionally before finishing. 
Please reread, because I think that code can't solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in Python, but I think that you should also represent each coalition $S$ by its unique integer representation, i.e. $\sum_{i \in S}\, 2^{i-1}$. For example, the coalition $S={3,4}$ is represented by $2^{3-1}+2^{4-1}=4+8=12$, whereas, coalition $S={2,3,4}$ is given by $2^{2-1}+2^{3-1}+2^{4-1}=2+4+8=14$. In Matlab all coalitions of a four-person TU game can be given through

```
N=2^n-1;
S=1:N
```

whereas $n=4$, and $N$ is the grand coalition ${1,2,3,4}$. This implies that you only need to specify the coalitional values by an array like

```
v = [0     0     5     0     0     0    40     0    10    40   100   100   160   190   250];
```

Of course, the coalition order is different from your approach. To see that, notice that coalition $S={1,2}$ is here located at position $3$ with a value of $5$ ($v({1,2})=5$), and coalition $S={3}$ at position $4$ with a value of zero ($v({3})=0$). I guess that under Python exists also a command like bitget under Matlab to single out which bits (players) belong to the number (coalition) $27$ for $n=5$.

For demonstration, let us compute the Shapley value for the above game $v$. We need only to pass the coalitional values to the function ShapleyValue() to get

```
>> sh_v=ShapleyValue(v)

sh_v =

      29.5833   44.5833   73.7500  102.0833
```

More details are given by my Matlab Game Theory Toolbox that can be found here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35933-mattugames